# Is there a name for this construct and has it always been supported?

Tags: javascript, compatibility

I am using this JavaScript construct:

```
new Function('return true;')();
```

I wonder if there is a name for it (calling the newly created Function object directly).

I checked the [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and it's ok.

I also wonder if this code will work in old browsers?

Comment: this looks like an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: is this question about the `new Function('return true;')` part or the whole thing?

Comment: Please take a look here [The Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_Function_constructor)  
`Note: Using the Function constructor to create functions is not recommended since it needs the function body as a string which may prevent some JS engine optimizations and can also cause other problems.`  
Anyway it is not recomended way of creating functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this pattern as [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

It's more commonly used like:

```
(function(){return true})()
```

I'm not sure there is a good reason to use the `Function` class directly as most use cases can be handled using the normal function declaration methods listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Function).

More information on using `Function` directly [here](https://javascript.info/new-function)

I don't see why it should not work on older browsers but I have not tested it myself

Comment: I need the *Function* class to check if *let* is supported.